# ¿Como añadir datos en un objeto local usando una POST Request con Node?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Se usar express para crear una nueva colección/tabla cuando se hace una post request, por ejemplo:

```
router.post('/lista', (req, res, next) => {

Lista.create(req.body).then((list) => {
    res.send(list)
}).catch(next)
```

})

Así creo una nueva List en la tabla "Lista" de mi base de datos.

Pero y si lo que tengo en vez de una base de datos es datos escritos a mano en la propia carpeta del servidor?

archivo **data.js**:

```js
let store = {
  posts: [

    {
      name: 'Top 10 ES6 Features every Web Developer must know',
      url: 'https://webapplog.com/es6',
      text: "This essay will give you a quick introduction to ES6. If you don’t know what is ES6, it’s a new JavaScript implementation.",
      comments: [
        { text: 'Cruel…..var { house, mouse} = No type optimization at all' },
        { text: 'I think you’re undervaluing the benefit of ‘let’ and ‘const’.' },
        { text: '(p1,p2)=>{ … } ,i understand this ,thank you !' }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
module.exports = store;
```

Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido para crear un nuevo `post` en **data.js** :

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const data = require('../hard-coded-Data/data')

 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
        data.posts += {
            name: req.body.name,
            url: req.body.url,
            text: req.body.text,
            comments: [
                req.body.comments
            ]
          }.then(() => res.send(data.posts))
    })
```

Pero como esperaba, no funciona.

Es porque hay errores de sintaxis y los objetos no se pueden editar así o directamente una operación así no se puede hacer de este modo tan a la ligera y Debería usar por ejemplo el modulo [fs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_file_system.htm) de node?

Esta es la estructura de la carpeta del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error que me devuelve:

> TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function

Y esto es lo que le paso cuando hago el post:

```
{
"name": "New post",
"url": "https://webapplog.com/es6",
"text": "This essay will give you a quick introduction to ES6. If you don’t know what is ES6, it’s a new JavaScript implementation.",
"comments": [
  {
    "text": "Cruel…..var { house, mouse} = No type optimization at all"
  },
  {
    "text": "I think you’re undervaluing the benefit of ‘let’ and ‘const’."
  },
  {
    "text": "(p1,p2)=>{ … } ,i understand this ,thank you !"
  }
]
```

}

Comment: Dices que no funciona, pero no comentas qué error obtienes. En principio sí debería funcionar, el error debe ser más sutil de lo que piensas.

Comment: @PabloLozano cierto se me olvido, esto es lo que me aparece: TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function. Puede ser que le esté pasando mal los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando hacer una operación muy rara, que es concatenar un elemento a un array.

El resultado de tratar de concatenar dos objetos es que cada objeto se transforma a string (generalmente se queda algo como `"[object Object]"`) y luego se concatenan los dos strings.

Si lo que quieres es añadir un elemento a un array, usa `push`:

```js
let data = {
  posts: [
    {
      name: 'Top 10 ES6 Features every Web Developer must know',
      url: 'https://webapplog.com/es6',
      text: "This essay will give you a quick introduction to ES6. If you don’t know what is ES6, it’s a new JavaScript implementation.",
      comments: [
        { text: 'Cruel…..var { house, mouse} = No type optimization at all' },
        { text: 'I think you’re undervaluing the benefit of ‘let’ and ‘const’.' },
        { text: '(p1,p2)=>{ … } ,i understand this ,thank you !' }
      ]
    }

  ]
};

data.posts.push({
  name: 'name',
  url: 'url',
  text: 'text',
  comments: [
      ''
  ]
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.posts));
```

En cualquier caso, estás esperando que la operación devuelva una promesa, porque realizas una llamada a `.then()`. Pero ni un array ni un String son promesas, con lo que el método `then` no está presente.

Por tanto la solución es sencilla:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const data = require('../hard-coded-Data/data')

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  data.posts.push({
    name: req.body.name,
    url: req.body.url,
    text: req.body.text,
    comments: [
        req.body.comments
    ]
  });
  //la operacion push es síncrona, no necesitas hacer más
  res.send(data.posts);
});
```